# What's the tile distribution in Words With Friends's Fast Play mode?

Tags: words-with-friends

I'm creating a AI that plays Scrabble / Words with Friends. I'm familiar with the tile count distribution in standard versions of both games ([this list is one example](http://tile-counter.com/wwf-tile-distribution-and-letter-frequency)), but Words with Friends recently released a new game mode in which a smaller board is used with fewer tiles. Does anybody happen to know what the tile count distribution is in this new mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This screenshot shows the tile bag immediately after starting a new Fast Play game. You'll notice the "tiles left" count does not match the sum of the tiles "in the bag" (so that you can't cheat.)

[image: tile distribution screenshot]

A-5
B-1
C-1
D-2
E-7
F-1
G-1
H-1
I-4
J-1
K-1
L-2
M-1
N-2
O-4
P-1
Q-1
R-2
S-4
T-2
U-1
V-1
W-1
X-1
Y-1
Z-1
BLANK-2

Total: 52 tiles